# Same code different outputs for fitting Truncated Normal Distribution

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution

I am running the same piece of code, with the same seed, same package versions, same R version, on 3 different systems: 1) my computer 2) a linux cluster and 3) [R snippets](https://rdrr.io/snippets/)

```r
packageVersion("truncnorm")
packageVersion("MASS")
set.seed(42)
fit<-NULL
x <- c(0.0916, 0.0084, 0.0442, 0.6254, 0.2021, 0.0135, 0.0259,
       0.1557,0.0191, 0.3575, 0.1843, 0.1792, 0.0476, 0.0765, 
       0.0356, 0.0039, 0.1714, 0.1222, 0.2872, 0.395, 0.3334,
       0.2223, 0.0096, 0.0436, 0.207)
mu0 <- mean(x)
sigma0 <- stats::sd(x)
fit <- MASS::fitdistr(x, densfun = function(xx, mu, sigma) {
    truncnorm::dtruncnorm(xx, a = 0, b = 1, mean = mu, sd = sigma)
}, 
   start = list(mu = mu0, sigma = sigma0), 
   lower = list(mu = -Inf, sigma = 0.05), 
   upper = list(mu = Inf, sigma = Inf))
print(fit)
```

On my computer, `fit` is showing as `NULL`, whereas in the other 2 systems, the model does fit successfully. Any ideas how that is possible?

P.S.: The issue on my system is

> Error in MASS::fitdistr(x, densfun = function(xx, mu, sigma) { : optimization failed

If I change the data a little bit, for example remove `0.0084` from the data (this is the second number in the data), the model fits. Giving me the same outputs across all 3 systems.

Here is the `sessionInfo()` from my own system:

> R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252
> LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United
> States.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C
> LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
> datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] truncnorm_1.0-8 MASS_7.3-51.4
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] ks_1.13.2
> compiler_3.6.0     Matrix_1.2-17      mclust_5.4.7       tools_3.6.0
> simIReff_1.0        [7] mvtnorm_1.1-3      KernSmooth_2.23-15
> grid_3.6.0         pracma_2.3.3       lattice_0.20-38

Comment: @BenBolker I don't believe this is possible. The `MASS` is `7.3.51.4` and the `truncnorm ` is `1.0.8` on both my system and the cluster. However, the issue is not on the cluster, but in my system as I said in the question. The results I get in `R snippets` align with the cluster.

Comment: I don't think installation order will matter here.  You can always revert to the old version of `MASS` by doing `remotes::install_version("MASS", "7.3.51.4")` (and you won't be any worse of than you are now if it (very surprisingly) doesn't get you back to the same state ...)

Comment: OK, I can reproduce "optimization failed" on a Windows virtual machine with current MASS/truncnorm. Now let's see where it goes from here ...

Comment: @BenBolker Interesting... thanks a lot for this info. I am still looking into it myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be a numerically unstable/sensitive problem.

If you turn on `debug(MASS::fitdistr)` and step through, eventually you'll get to a line

```r
 if (res$convergence > 0L) stop("optimization failed")
```

If you print out the value of `res` at this point you get (slightly abbreviated):

```
$par
       mu     sigma
-6.411168  1.022651
$value
[1] -21.72969
$counts
function gradient
      81       81
$convergence
[1] 52
$message
[1] "ERROR: ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH"
```

in other words, the L-BFGS-B optimizer (which is used because you specified bounds - it's quite finicky) thinks there is a problem, and `fitdistr` accordingly throws an error. As far as I can tell there is no way to tell `fitdistr` "just give me the answer anyway".

I tried a bunch of different methods (perturbing the starting conditions a little bit, i.e. `mu + 1e-3, sigma0 + 1e-3`; removing the bounds so that `fitdistr` uses the more robust Nelder-Mead optimizer instead). Plotting the `log10(1e-4 + neg log likelihood)` (so that we can see small differences from the minimum negative log-likelihood) gives the following image (code below):

[image: likelihood surface]

[red: Linux, green: Windows/convergence failure, blue: Windows/perturbed start, cyan: Nelder-Mead]

These are the corresponding fits to the distribution:

[image: histogram plus curves]

As you can see (or probably can't!), all the fits are basically identical. If you calculate the negative log-likelihood, you'll see that they differ by less than 0.001 units [i.e., negligibly]. (You can also tell this because all the points in the first image lie within the `log10(difference) = -3` contour.)

So the differences between answers don't really matter, just the annoyance of getting an error. You could (1) use a `while` loop + `try()` to perturb the starting value a little bit until you get an answer; (2) drop the bounds to allow Nelder-Mead to work: (3) use `bbmle` or some other tool that lets you be a little bit more robust/defensive about the optimization procedure ...

---

```r
nllfun <- function(mu, sigma) {
  -sum(log(dtruncnorm(x, a = 0, b = 1, mean = mu, sd = sigma)))
}
library(emdbook)
library(truncnorm)
p1 <- c(-7.02938981, 1.06779942) ## Linux
p2 <- c(-6.411, 1.022651)  ## Windows (convergence error)
p3 <- c(-6.587645, 1.0359466) ## Windows (perturbed start)
p4 <- c(-5.9937989, 0.9901366) ## Windows (Nelder-Mead/no bounds)
cc <- curve3d(nllfun(x,y), xlim = c(-7.1, -5.98), ylim = c(0.98, 1.07),
              n = c(101, 101), sys3d = "none")

image(cc$x, cc$y, log10(cc$z-min(cc$z) + 1e-4))
contour(cc$x, cc$y, log10(cc$z-min(cc$z) + 1e-4), add = TRUE)
points(p1[1], p1[2], pch = 16, col = 2)
points(p2[1], p2[2], pch = 17, col = 3)
points(p3[1], p3[2], pch = 18, col = 4)
points(p4[1], p4[2], pch = 18, col = 5)

hist(x, freq=FALSE)
curve(dtruncnorm(x, a=0, b=1, mean=p1[1], sd = p1[2]), col = 2, add=TRUE)
curve(dtruncnorm(x, a=0, b=1, mean=p2[1], sd = p2[2]), col = 3, add=TRUE)
curve(dtruncnorm(x, a=0, b=1, mean=p3[1], sd = p3[2]), col = 4, add=TRUE)
curve(dtruncnorm(x, a=0, b=1, mean=p4[1], sd = p4[2]), col = 5, add=TRUE)
```